# Can I clear an externally declared array for further use?

Tags: c++, arrays, variables, delete-operator

I have an .h file that declares `extern Obj *objArr;`. In my main .cpp file, outside on any functions I initialize `Obj *objArr;`. Inside my main() function, I call a function `runSim(int size)` twice in a row, with different arguments each time.

Ultimately, I need to access objArr in different .cpp files. This will happen after it is initialized with a size in the first line of runSim(). Hopefully, I can clear the objArr of it's contents and allocated size without actually deleting the external variable, so that it can be created anew with a different size and contents on the next call to runSim(). Will doing this `delete[]objArr` line actually accomplish what I am aiming to do?

```
//externalVars.h
extern Obj *objArr;

//main .cpp file
Obj *objArr;

void runSim(int size) {
    objArr = new Obj[size];
    //some things are done
    delete[]objArr;
}

int main() {
    runSim(1);
    runSim(8);
}
```

Thank you

Comment: `delete` has no effect on the variable itself, it just frees the memory that it points to.

Comment: It's the same with local and global variables.

Comment: Using extern global variable is not a good way of using same value in code from different .cpp files. Supply it explicitly as function parameter or by some other means.

Comment: @VTT What would be the disadvantages of using an external variable like this? How would you recommend I pass an array that's already initialized and allocated to functions across files using a function parameter? That does seem like it would be better design, but I can't think of how it would be done.

Comment: @J.Cal There are numerous articles explaining the pitfalls of global variables. The better design would be to make a function-local `std::vector<Obj>` and pass it around by (potentially const-qualified) reference.

Comment: Not sure I understand the use of extern in this example. You declare global pointer and use it in the same translation unit, why do you need extern?

Answer (score 0):

Use of

```
void runSim(int size) {
    objArr = new Obj[size];
    //some things are done
    delete[]objArr;
}
```

is technically correct but it smells of poor design.

If you are going to allocate *and* deallocate memory of the object in the function, it will be a lot cleaner to use a `std::vector` in the function scope.

```
void runSim(int size) {
    std::vector<Obj> objArr(size);

    //some things are done

    // No need for this
    // delete[]objArr;
}
```

If part of `//some things are done` involves using `objArr` in another, simply pass the object to the function that needs it. Say you use:

```
void runSim(int size) {
    objArr = new Obj[size];
    foo();
    delete[]objArr;
}
```

and `foo` uses `objArr`. Change `foo` to expect a `std::vector<Obj>&` or `std::vector<Obj> const&` as an argument instead of relying on a global variable.

```
void runSim(int size) {
    std::vector<Obj> objArr(size);
    foo(objArr);
}
```